# How to get the object's name in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, object, properties

I'm trying to dynamically adding and removing objects in my form. I'm stuck on how to get the unique identifier of which object to remove.

```
        'Collection of controls
        For Each ctl In Me.Controls
            'Get control type
            If TypeOf ctl Is Label Then
                'Get control name/index id/text or any property of current ctl
                'How do I continue from here?
                'Me.Controls.Remove(ctl)
            End If
        Next
```

Thanks in advance for solutions/suggestions.
If it's alright, I would like to know the explanation of the solutions.

If you guys need to know how I added objects dynamically, here it is:

```
        For i = 1 To Spots
            Dim newLabel As New Label
            Dim newLoc As Integer = iLoc + (i * 30)

            With newLabel
                .Name = "lblSpot" & i
                .Text = "Spot " & i
                .Size = New Size(100, 20)
                .Location = New Point(3, newLoc)
            End With

            AddHandler Me.Load, AddressOf frmParking_Load
            Me.Controls.Add(newLabel)
        Next
```

Comment: How would you be deciding which ones to delete in the first place?

Comment: By object's property name. As you can see, I named the dynamic labels as "lblSpot" + i(the number of spots).

It would appear in my mind like this:
If ctl.Name = "lblSpot" & i Then
Me.Controls.Remove(ctl)
End If

Comment: Yea so just `if ctl.Name == "NAME_TO_DELETE"` and then delete the ones you want

Comment: ctl.Name is not available :(

Comment: Ok I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast `ctl` to `Label` and then use `.Name` to find the controls to delete

Comment: Thanks. Now, I need to add handlers for each control I created. I'm going to do some self programming, I would need help but that's another topic for another day :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Using For Each when change collection is not recommended, so here is the code you want

```
Dim i = 0
While i < Me.Controls.Count
    Dim c = Me.Controls(i)
    If TypeOf c Is Label Then
        Dim Lbl As Label = CType(c, Label)
        If Lbl.Name.Contains("lblSpot") Then
            Me.Controls.Remove(c)
        End If
    End If
End While
```